# How to download email attachments in c#

Tags: c#, email, attachment, download

Are there any free libraries I can use in c# to download email attachments?  Yes, this question has been posted before, but previous posts are getting old and some projects referenced in them are not even maintained anymore.  I'm hoping something new has come out in the last couple years.

Also, I'd prefer something that will work with anything but a solution specific to Exchange Server would be okay as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EA GetMail Component](http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/).Here i given an example to get attachment from email using IMAP potocol

```
MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");

//ServerProtocol.Pop3 to ServerProtocol.Imap4 in MailServer constructor

MailServer oServer  = new MailServer(sServer, 
sUserName, sPassword, bSSLConnection, 
ServerAuthType.AuthLogin, ServerProtocol.Imap4);

//by default, the pop3 port is 110, imap4 port is 143, 
//the pop3 ssl port is 995, imap4 ssl port is 993
//you can also change the port like this
//oServer.Port = 110;

 oClient.Connect(oServer);
 MailInfo [] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
 int count = infos.Length;
 if(count!=0)
 {
   MailInfo info = infos[i];
   Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);
   Attachment [] atts = oMail.Attachments;          
 }
```

Comment: That looks nice, but their standard license is too restrictive (i.e. I would have to choose between developing in my laptop or desktop... which is just stupid) and their professional license looks to be about 60% more expensive than Mail.dll which would also do what I need.  Looks like a nice interface though.